# number of ways poker card question

Tags: probability, permutations

I am having difficulties to calculate the number of ways 11 poker card can be chosen such that  two cards of one suit, two cards of another suit, four cards of another suit, three cards of another suit.

I am thinking something like this:

> $(4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1){13\choose 2}{13\choose 4}{13\choose 3}$

Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for showing your answer.  You got more specific answers that way.  Better yet to show how you got there.  In this case it was clear, but not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer should be divided by two because the order of the two suits in which you are picking two cards does not matter.

One way to think about this is: you choose the suit in which in need four cards and three cards, which has $4\times 3\times C(13, 4)\times C(13,3)$ ways. Then, take any suit and pick two cards, take the other one and pick two cards, so you get another $C(13, 2)\times C(13, 2)$ ways.

Comment: so, do you mean the solution is 4*3*C(13,4)*C(13,3)*C(13,2)*C(13,2)?

Comment: @user1988385 Right.

Answer (score 3):

No, you've counted the number of ways of getting 2 spades and 2 hearts twice.

The real number is $$\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2\cdot 1 \binom{13}{2}^2\binom{13}{4}\binom{13}{3}$$